# jQuery draggable quiz boxes

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I've spent hours reading forum and watching examples without result. Please I need to do this:
I have 6 boxes (in box is not only img)

[ img ] [ img ] [ img ] [ img ] [ img ] [ img ]

and 6 empty boxes:

{  .  } {  .  } {  .  } {  .  } {  .  } {  .  }

How to drag and drop that elements with img in any empty box? But only in it, somewhere else it should not drop. And then i need to get count of dragged elements. That boxes can be dropped in any empty box, it doesn't matter. I tried HTML5 drag and drop and that was very bad. Can someone please help me? The best solution should be link on the same problem or full code.

Thank you very much

Comment: Look this: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#accepted-elements, you can edit it and make it like you want

Comment: but it is possible to drop it anywhere, i need only in that empty box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs to be styled a bit but i think this should work? http://jsfiddle.net/wfG3L/451/ Just add the images to the .Card divs and it should work

```
$(".stackDrop1").droppable({
tolerance: "intersect",
accept: ".card",
activeClass: "ui-state-default",
hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
drop: function(event, ui) {
    if ($('.stackDrop1').is(':empty')){
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
    }
}
});
```

This checks if the div is droppable and if the box is still empty.

Comment: +10 000 if i could :) thank you very much u save my life :) but one question, that dropped element is pulled down, how to put it exactly in that empty box?

Comment: Im not sure what causes that but with some css styles it should be an easy fix the jquery works fine so thats not the problem

Comment: And is it possible to block moving after "pasting" it in drop area? I want drop it down and not moving more (only by clicking on it, it should go back)

Comment: Remove the class .card from the div if its dropped so add .removeclass to the function when dropped. And add a click function with $(this).append($(#launchPad)); This should move it back when clicked